# ssl_verify_result is 0, when no https version is available

Tags: php, curl, ssl

I have a site that's using http and not https. When I now use `cURL` the http-Version gets the `http_code = 200`. When I now use the https-Version it gets `0`, which is okay, since there is no https version of the site. But the problem is, that ssl_verifiy_result is 0, which means:

the operation was successful

source: http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/verify.html#VERIFY_OPERATION

Why is that?

Comment: Sure, I will, if you tell me why you need the code? I'm using simple curl request in php. Just using the basic methods with these additional options

`returntrasnfer => true | verifypeer => false | followlocation => true`

The rest is just basic curl. i.e. : curl_init, curl_execute etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug within openSSL. This feature is only useful when you have:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);`

See also:

`If no peer certificate was presented, the returned result code is X509_V_OK. This is because no verification error occurred, it does however not indicate success. SSL_get_verify_result() is only useful in connection with SSL_get_peer_certificate(3).`

http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_get_verify_result.html#bugs

Remember that when you want cURL to connect to SSL and verify the certificate you priorly have to download and save the CA certificate (firefox can do this) to your application and reference it in your cURL call. For example:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/CACertificats/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt");
```

Small tutorial about this: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Comment: "...has been unsuccessful" - I'm not sure that is correct. `ssl_verifiy_result` comes from the OpenSSL library, and I believe that its `X509__OK`. According to the OpenSSL [man page on SSL_get_verify_result](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_get_verify_result.html), *"The verification succeeded or no peer certificate was presented."*. It looks like a potential bug in cURL. cURL should probably indicate there was no SSL/TLS, and not indicate success (since cURL is layered over top the SSL library).

Comment: @jww Apparently it is. It says it also in the doc `If no peer certificate was presented, the returned result code is X509_V_OK. This is because no verification error occurred, it does however not indicate success. SSL_get_verify_result() is only useful in connection with SSL_get_peer_certificate(3).` Stupid.

Comment: SSL verification is `true` by default